# Sidebar site logos aren't resized correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, logo

I recently noticed some ugly aliasing in the sidebar site list:

[image]

I actually solved this problem before in my SE app (no linky here, that would be bad. It's in my profile). It turns out you can't just put a big UIImage into a small UIImageView. You have to resize the image itself.

What I did was use `UIImage+ProportionalFill` from the [MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities). I replaced:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

with

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithData:imgData] imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)/*<-- Put your size here*/];
```

And that makes it look a whole lot better.

Comment: -1 for making me go to your profile to find the link to your SE app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an update I believe will address this problem; however, I'm going to do a little profiling on it before putting it in a build.  You *might* see it sometime tonight, *if* there's a build.  If not, then probably tomorrow.