# Questions list does not show new questions (iOS app)

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Right now the top question I see in the app is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221029/sidebar-site-logos-arent-resized-correctly), while obviously there are newer questions.

The time difference appears to be two hours, and I'm in GMT+2 timezone so maybe it's related?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. It isn't API caching, because Stackboard picks up more recent questions. Maybe app-side caching?

Comment: @Undo what's your timezone? Maybe it's a bug related to local time vs. server time...

Comment: I'm on Mountain time (UTC-7). The difference is two hours for me too, though.

Comment: Hmm... and what is the top question you see?

Comment: Currently on Meta, "Better sorting on Site Search" is first (with a sort of Creation), and a timestamp of 3 hours ago.

Comment: Different than what I see but no direct relation to timezone... well, hopefully the team can figure this out. :)

Comment: I think it's skipping the first page or so of results, maybe a bug related to the fix for filtering out closed questions.

Comment: @Tim so how it is different for each user? Page size should be the same, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the bit about it being different for everyone.

Comment: So far one hour difference between Undo and myself, @Tim but what you see as top question?

Comment: Right now it's The all sites table view isn't resized when searching
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221060/the-all-sites-table-view-isnt-resized-when-searchin

Comment: @Tim same here! Weird.

Comment: Good catch.  Investigating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [some filtering we are doing (temporarily) on <strike>closed</strike> "on hold" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220368/closed-question-status-isnt-indicated-anywhere), but because of a simple oversight, the first page of questions in the questions list was getting lost.  This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Next is 0.1.17?

Comment: Yes, or later (once in a while we'll have a snafu with a build and wind up skipping one).

Comment: Thanks, now I see even shiny new questions. :)