# The all sites table view isn't resized when searching

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When I go to the site list from the sidebar, there's a handy little search bar there to aid me in finding my one site out of hundreds. And it works quite well.

However, when searching with the keyboard up, the table view isn't resized so as to allow scrolling through all the content - instead, the bottom four or five rows are hidden behind the keyboard.

This screenshot is with the table view scrolled down as far as possible:

[image]

This means that I have to hit the search button to dismiss the keyboard to tap on some of the sites, rendering the live search feature of limited usefulness.

This can be fixed by simply changing the table view's frame when the keyboard is being shown. Plz fixy?

Comment: Having not visited that section of the app before, I'd like to also add that clearing the list when tapping the search field is jarring. Empty search should show all

Comment: Thanks for the report @Undo, I'm taking a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the table definitely needed resizing when the keyboard appeared.

**This will be fixed in version 0.1.17**